# Как убрать пропуски данных в дата сете

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, обработка-данных

Написал код, чтобы появлялись пропущенные значения. И хотелось бы понять можно ли их как то заполнить при том что они появляются рандомно?
Вот сам код:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)
a = np.sin(a) + [random.gauss(0, 0.2) for i in range(len(a))]
for i in range(10):
    a[random.randint(0, len(a) - 1)] = None
#здесь как я понимаю импутация
plt.plot(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку пропуски одиночные, проще всего наверное использовать `Pandas`:

```
for i in range(10):
    a[random.randint(0, len(a) - 1)] = np.nan
s = pd.Series(a)
s = s.fillna(method='pad')
plt.plot(s);
```

- в пропусках должно быть специальное значение `np.nan`, а не `None` (хотя это можно легко переделать, если там будет всё же `None`)
- делаем `Pandas Series` из `numpy array`
- используем специальную функцию `fillna`, используя для заполнения предыдущее значение серии